# How do I set the default target framework in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

I would like all my project to default to .Net 3.5 when creating a new project, but it initially defaults to 2.0. I've spent a few hours online, and and a few hours digging through project templates. No luck.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio always remembers the target framework setting you chose the last time you used the "New Project" dialog.

If you create a new project using the .NET Framework 3.5 setting the selection defaults to .NET 3.5 until you create a project with a different setting.

Comment: @Boris: Great! Please accept and vote up the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new project (*File -> New -> Project...*) and make sure that *.NET Framework 3.5* is selected as the target framework in the **New Project** window (dropdown in the top right of the window). It should then become the default for future new projects.